# duplicate key error collection: mydatabase.customers index: _id_ dup key

Tags: python, mongodb

I want to check if the user exists. If user does exist, do not insert it.

**This is my code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Python code to illustrate
# inserting data in MongoDB
from pymongo import MongoClient

try:
    myclient  = MongoClient('10.1.3.18',27017)
    print("Connected successfully!!!")
except:
    print("Could not connect to MongoDB")

# database
emp_rec1 = {
        "name":"Mr.Geek1",
        "eid":24,
        "location":"delhi"
        }
emp_rec2 = {
        "name":"Mr.Shaurya",
        "eid":14,
        "location":"delhi"
        }

emp_rec3 = {
        "name":"Mr.Shaurya111",
        "eid":141111,
        "location":"delhi111111"
        }
a=[emp_rec1,emp_rec2,emp_rec3]
mydb = myclient["mydatabase"]
#result = mydb.profiles.create_index([('user_id'],unique=True)
mycol = mydb["customers"]

#x = mycol.insert_one(a[2])
cursor = mycol.find()
for record in cursor:
    print(record)
    mydb.servers.getIndexes()
    if record['name']!="Mr.Shaurya":
        x = mycol.insert_one(a[0])
        print(record)
```

Is this code correct? Or there is an other solution?

**and if I run my code twice I get this error:**

```
pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: 
mydatabase.customers index: _id_ dup key: { :ObjectId('5d7b9a6bc9a8569a44a6da2c') }
```

How to prevent duplicated key in MongoDB?
How can I use index?

Comment: Do you have the `SQL insert` you are using

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `eid` is your Primary Key column that is causing the Duplicate Key error, the code below should fix your problem.

When you loop through `cursor`, you want to also loop through you array `a` and see if the `eid` in a also exists in database `cursor`. If it does not exist, then record will be inserted using `x = mycol.insert_one(a[0])`

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Python code to illustrate
# inserting data in MongoDB
from pymongo import MongoClient

try:
    myclient  = MongoClient('10.1.3.18',27017)
    print("Connected successfully!!!")
except:
    print("Could not connect to MongoDB")

# database
emp_rec1 = {
        "name":"Mr.Geek1",
        "eid":24,
        "location":"delhi"
        }
emp_rec2 = {
        "name":"Mr.Shaurya",
        "eid":14,
        "location":"delhi"
        }

emp_rec3 = {
        "name":"Mr.Shaurya111",
        "eid":141111,
        "location":"delhi111111"
        }
a=[emp_rec1,emp_rec2,emp_rec3]
mydb = myclient["mydatabase"]
#result = mydb.profiles.create_index([('user_id'],unique=True)
mycol = mydb["customers"]

#x = mycol.insert_one(a[2])
cursor = mycol.find()
for record in cursor:
    print(record)
    mydb.servers.getIndexes()

    for i in a:
         if record['eid'] != i['eid']:
              x = mycol.insert_one(a[0])
              print(record)
```

If you want to strictly check only the name of user in `customers` table, you can use the following query.

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Python code to illustrate
# inserting data in MongoDB
from pymongo import MongoClient

try:
    myclient  = MongoClient('10.1.3.18',27017)
    print("Connected successfully!!!")
except:
    print("Could not connect to MongoDB")

# database
emp_rec1 = {
        "name":"Mr.Geek1",
        "eid":24,
        "location":"delhi"
        }
emp_rec2 = {
        "name":"Mr.Shaurya",
        "eid":14,
        "location":"delhi"
        }

emp_rec3 = {
        "name":"Mr.Shaurya111",
        "eid":141111,
        "location":"delhi111111"
        }
a=[emp_rec1,emp_rec2,emp_rec3]
mydb = myclient["mydatabase"]
#result = mydb.profiles.create_index([('user_id'],unique=True)
mycol = mydb["customers"]

#x = mycol.insert_one(a[2])
cursor = mycol.find()
for record in cursor:
    print(record)
    mydb.servers.getIndexes()

    for i in a:
         if record['name'] != i['name']:
              x = mycol.insert_one(a[0])
              print(record)
```

Comment: mydb.servers.getIndexes()